# CodeIgniter CSS relative links

Tags: css, codeigniter

I've looked at other answers involving this question, but still can't get it to work. I'm trying to link my CSS file relatively. I've tried the `base_url()` concat and it still doesn't work. Maybe I just have a misconception about CI URLs. Anyway, my CSS file is under `views->templates->Item_CSS.css`

I have tried everything and still get no results. If anyone can help I'd be grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to reach that path easily, since codeigniter uses it's index.php (situated in the root) to handle everything. The **views** folder isn't the base path

What I do is to add a **css** and **js** folder in the root of CI (where index.php,.htaccess lies), after that your css routes will be `www.example.com/css/mycss.css` or `base_url().css/mycss.css`.

In case you get a forbidden error you might need to modify the .htaccess to allow accessing those folders

Comment: +1, it makes sense to leave CSS at the root of the site, as it doesn't really fit the definition of a "view", imo.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you config your base url as:

`$config['base_url']   = 'http://www.abc.com/';`

and you put the `application` folder where the `system` and `index.php` file is. Then use the following code:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>application/views/templates/Item_CSS.css" />`